# XP file server - grant access to specific LAN users

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, file-sharing, lan

I have a XP PRO (SP3) machine that acts as a file server on our network. Currently there are several shared folders that everyone has access to, however I need to create a new share that only certain LAN PC's/Users can access.

What I have tried so far

1. Creating a local user on the XP machine called 'TEST' with password '12345'
2. Removing the 'Everyone' permission rule on the shared folder
3. Creating a new permission rule for user 'TEST' (full access)

However when I now try and access the shared folder from another machine on the LAN I just get a permissions error.

What I would like to happen is either....

That the user on the PC trying to access the share be prompted with a login box where they could enter the credentials for the 'TEST' user I created (and hopefully then be able to save the password for future use).

OR

Create local user accounts on the file server that match the user names of the of the LAN users that are permitted to access the share, and then give them the appropriate access rights in the permissions management.

Many Thanks

p.s. I have noticed that when adding new user permissions there is a location field (that is locked) that has the file servers name in it by default, is there anyway to select another workstation within the same workgroup here ?

Edit: Simple file sharing is turned off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is simple file sharing turned on? The reason I ask is because there are no passwords or access restrictions and, with one exception, everything that's shared is accessible by everyone on the network.

What you want to do is doable using ACL's without creating another Test 'local user'. I read through [this article](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/sharing/xp_filesharing/index.htm). It explains how to disable simple file sharing and it also explains how to setup a folder so only desired users can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the rushed response....

1. The "Everyone" permission, select Full Control.
2. Create local accounts on the file server for the different users who are trying to access. Restrict the permissions through each account on the file server.

> p.s. I have noticed that when adding
>   new user permissions there is a
>   location field (that is locked) that
>   has the file servers name in it by
>   default, is there anyway to select
>   another workstation within the same
>   workgroup here ?

No, this is reserved for selecting users/computers through a domain and through the local PC.